# UISwitches lagging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch that changes the text of a UILabel right above it upon switching the value. Every once in a while (perhaps 2% of the time) the text doesn't change. The text of the label gets saved to a text file and thus I need accuracy. Since this issue is so intermittent it's extremely hard to debug. I thought perhaps the main thread was being blocked or something but the app isn't using nearly any resources at all. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Here's some code of the IBAction for the switch.

```
- (IBAction)type:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isOn]) {

        //change label
        self.typeLabel.text = @"ventless";

        //change property of string to be saved into text file
        self.typeString = @"ventless";
    }
    else{
        self.typeLabel.text = @"standard";
        self.typeString = @"standard";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you write to a file, it would be required to see how you store this information. With the provided information, there is nothing wrong at all, but consider a I/O operation in the current days, is not a massive thing but depending how many data, if you are parsing it before to write, and more details to be taken, etc., can delay the update of the user interface. You can always open instruments and check whats going wrong, it will say the amount of memory and time you are spending in the I/O operation. I would recommend to do a test using UnitTesting and read/write 100 times and see what happens. The use of instruments in this case of performance is a must and should give you spare information to know what´s happening in your app.